# Using friendship in test

Tags: c++, testing, friend

I'm looking for a "clean" way of accessing some private member variables in a test context without touching the original code. I was thinking about implementing a **friendship** relation with the test class, but for some reason I do not understand it still requires a **protected** accessor in order to work. Why is it like that? Is there any other way to access the private member variable?

```
class A
{
protected:    // this works
// private:   // this DOES not work


    int a;
};

class TestableA : public A
{
    friend class TestA;
};

class TestA
{
    void test()
    {
        m_a.a = 100;
    }

    TestableA m_a;
};
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't access a private variable from a derived class, only protecteds.

`TestA` is a friend of `TestableA`, so it can see everything `TestableA` contains. But if `a` is private, you can't access it in `TestableA`.

You have several options:

- use protected everywhere
- add the friend declarations to class `A` directly. You can even do it with a macro, which only effects the debug/test build.

For more information about this topic, there's a good presentation called [Friendship in Service of Testing](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=IF4LhMwVvSc)

Comment: Thank for explaining the reason and for the link. The idea was to not modify the original code, but it seems there's no other way.

Comment: The video is about this problem - it proposes a way of adding friends for this case outside the class, currently implemented as a clang plugin.